# Debugging in Electron: how can I access render-scope objects from the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, electron

In web development, I always found it useful that I could get read, write and execution access to 
variables and functions via the browser's development console at runtime. For example, if I have a

```
 var foo = 3;
```

in my code, then I could do this at runtime:

[image]

**Is there a mechanism to do the same thing in Electron with elements from the render scope?** While Electron has the Chromium development console, trying the above gives a `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined`.

(By *render scope*, I refer to elements defined in the `render.js` file that runs in the browser window I opened the console in. The script is included via `<script> require('./render.js'); </script>` at the end of the HTML body.)

Comment: *elements from the render scope* - what exactly do you mean? In the console, you're referring to a global, `window.foo`.

Comment: @estus As in, the file that runs in the specific browser window. It is included via a `<script>
      require('./render.js');
    </script>` in the HTML-file at the end of the document body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this in your html file to include your js:

```
...my html...
<script src="./render.js"></script>

</html>
```

In your render.js file include your example e.g. "var foo = 3;". Should work.